# Analysing root cause of file system errors in Debian

Tags: debian, filesystems, errors

My VPS hosting provider just helped me to restart my Debian VPS after it failed to reboot. He told me there were file system errors but told me to refer to the logs in order to find out what happened.

What kinds of things should I be grepping for here and in which log files?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why type of virtualization do you use?

Comment: It's using Xen virtualization

Comment: Try to look at /var/log/messages and /var/log/dmesg. Maybe you'll see something.

Answer (score 0):

Messages on file system errors can vary. However, I would run a file system check and repair any faults. `fsck` is a good start.